# Find the cdf $F_{X,Y}(u,v)$ if the pdf is given by $f_{X,Y}(x,y) = 6x$ for $0\leq x \leq 1$ and $0 \leq y \leq 1-x$

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics, probability-distributions

Find the cdf $F_{X,Y}(u,v)$ if the pdf  is given by $$f_{X,Y}(x,y) = 6x$$ for $0\leq x \leq 1$ and $0 \leq y \leq 1-x$

I have the solution to this, but I don't understand it completely. Can some one explain why there are two cases to consider.

Case I: When $v<1-u$ and Case II: when $v>1-u$.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Sketch a diagram of the support on the x,y-plane.    It is a right triangle which is the lower-left half of the unit square.

The region $0\leq x\leq u\leq 1, 0\leq y \leq v\leq 1-u$ corresponds to a rectangle completely within that triangle.

The region $0\leq x\leq u\leq 1, 1-u\leq y\leq v\leq 1$ corresponds to a rectangle that extends beyond the support (and you only want to cumulate the probability of areas within the support).